# Cambiar color de una fila en Treeview

Tags: python, tkinter

Se puede cambiar el color de una fila de Treeview? Lo he intentado mediante tag_configure, pero por lo que he leido en la última versión de Python ya no funciona.
Básicamente lo que quiero es alternar el color entre filas pares e impares.

```
for i in lista:


        if lista.index(i) % 2== 0:
            Tabla.insert('', 0, text=i[0], values=(i[1], i[2]), tags='par')

        else: 
            Tabla.insert('', 0, text=i[0], values=(i[1], i[2]), tags='impar')
```

Los tags los he configurado así:

```
Tabla.tag_configure('par',background='white',foreground='black')
Tabla.tag_configure('impar',background='black',foreground='white')
```

Conoceis alguna manera de definir el color de fondo de una fila que no sea por tags?

Answer (score 0):

He mirado la documentación para Python 3.8 y no veo nada que indique que no se puede hacer lo que dices. De hecho otra respuestas similares no parece que se desvíen mucho de tu solución propuesta y me parece la más correcta y los tags son para lo que tu propones. Asegúrate de crear los tags justo después de declarar el treeview y antes de rellenar los rows.

Comment: Pués no funciona, o no logra hacerlo funcionar

Comment: Cierto, no funciona. No salta ningún error y aparentemente debería ser así. Si tengo un hueco intentaré ejecutarlo en linux por si fuera alguna incompatibilidad

Comment: Por lo que he podido leer se trata de un fallo en la biblioteca tkinter. Se corregirá en próximas versiones.

Comment: Lo acabo de probar en Manjaro KDE y tampoco alterna colores de fondo. Es posible que sea lo que dices.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno el código para mostrarlo sería algo parecido a esto, y no no funciona. Lo que hace es extraer los datos de una tabla SQL y mostrarlos. (Atención soy novato)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3

root=Tk()

FrameTabla=Frame(root)
FrameTabla.pack()
def mostrar_items():

    try:
        miConexion=sqlite3.connect("database")
        miCursor=miConexion.cursor()


        miCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM DATABASE ORDER BY USERID DESC")

        lista=miCursor.fetchall()

        for i in lista:


            if lista.index(i) % 2 == 0:
                Tabla.insert('', 0, text=i[0], values=(i[1], i[2]), tags=('par',))


            else: 
                Tabla.insert('', 0, text=i[0], values=(i[1], i[2]), tags=('impar',))

        miConexion.close()

    except:
        pass

Tabla=ttk.Treeview(FrameTabla, heigh=20, columns=("Nombre", "Apellido"))
Tabla.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
Tabla.tag_configure('par',background='white',foreground='black')
Tabla.tag_configure('impar',background='black',foreground='white')
Tabla.heading('#0', text = 'UserID', anchor = CENTER)
Tabla.heading('Nombre', text = 'Nombre', anchor = CENTER)
Tabla.heading('Apellido', text = 'Apellido', anchor = CENTER)
Tabla.column('#0', width=120, anchor= CENTER)
Tabla.column('Nombre', anchor = CENTER)
Tabla.column('Apellido', anchor = CENTER)

ScrollVert=Scrollbar(FrameTabla, command=Tabla.yview)
ScrollVert.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky='nsew')
mostrar_items()

root.mainloop()
```